# Java regex with branch selector

Tags: java, regex, branch, selector

Is there any way to somehow set a value in the same field across different `Java` regex "branches", so that a switch-like statement later on can identify which branch was followed?

For example, in a `PCRE` with 3 "branches" like

```
(\S+|d+|\s+)
```

the ideal answer would be to have a common variable (say, `selector`) that would be set to different values (say, "non-space", "digit" and "space"), so that a `switch` statement like

```
case "non-space":
case "digit":
case "space":
```

can be executed afterwards.

The use case relates to a regex engine that understands `Java` regular expressions but does not allow execution of `Java` code, so if there is an answer, it has to be fully regex-based.

Probably the above can't be done, so any advise on workarounds is also welcome. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is not any regex selector available in Java.

However you car use `Matcher` and groups.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\S+)|(\\d+)|(\\s+)");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) != null) { // non-space

    }
    if (m.group(2) != null) { // digit

    }
    if (m.group(3) != null) { // space

    }
}
```

Comment: I could, but the regex engine does not allow Java code. So, it has to be a mechanism built-in to the regex mechanism, like the named captures.

Comment: Btw, what are the input and output parameters of the regex engine?

Comment: Java regex seem to support named captures `"(?<nonspace>\\S+)|(?<digit>\\d+)|(?<space>\\s+)"`, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Yes it does, but you cannot use the same name across more than one group. I don't want 3 different names, only one getting 3 different values, to do a switch on.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the closest you could get is the alternation (as you show) to
execute different code paths. Regex logic is a little different than  if/then/else logic.

```
 (?:
      (?:                # ----------
           (?<a> )            # (1)
                              # do a code
        |  (?<b> )            # (2)
                              # do b code
        |  (?<c> )            # (3)
                              # do c code
      )                  # ---------

      # Common code
 )+
```

PCRE has additional logic called conditionals. It's most like a switch statement.

```
 (?:                # ----------
      (?:
           (?<a> )            # (1)
        |  (?<b> )            # (2)
        |  (?<c> )            # (3)
      )                  # ---------

      (?(<a>)            # did a match
                              # do a code
        |                   # else
           (?(<b>)            # did b match
                                   # do b code
             |                   # else
                                   # do c code
           )
      )

      # Common code
 )+
```

But, as you can see, there is really no difference between the two in this
context.

The *primary* and really only use for regex conditionals ( imo )
is as a flag to fail or accept a match at a certain point in the code.
This gives the engine a chance to retry a different combination.  `(?(<a>)|(?!))`

Keep in mind that the use of  *assertions* will go a long way to inject logic
into the code. This is available in the Java engine.

PCRE also have function call construct as well that can be called
recursively if needed to do balanced text matches. However, this is not
available in Java.

Comment: Your answer seems incomplete, but from whatever is there, you seem to be suggesting the use of named caption groups. This approach cannot be used, because it produces different variable names ("a", "b", "c"). The question was about a way to have the same variable name (say, "selector") that produces a different value per branch (e.g., selector="a", or selector="b", or selector="c").

Comment: @PNS - No need to repeat what you've stated in your question's post. You're groping for C language logic in regular expressions, i.e, the `switch` statement. It obviously doesn't exist. You also won't find any for min,max loops. You will find many ways to do logic in regex that don't exist in common language constructs. I thought you would already know that. Regex is fairly rich, and can do things that can't be done in common language simple constructs. If your intent is to somehow knock regular expressions with this misplaced comparisons, it won't work with the experts.

Comment: I asked a very clear question, knowing (and stating) that there is probably no answer. There is nothing wrong with that, as there is no need for negativity, conspiracy theories ("knock regular expressions"?) or lecturing. You did answer by explaining named groups, which is not what the question was about, and your answer is incomplete, in the sense that it ends with a half phrase ("For example,"...). That's all. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @PNS - Sorry for any misunderstanding, I just noticed the "For example". I must have been thinking earlier in the post of giving an array of examples demonstrating the logic that can be done in regex, and put a placeholder there. By the time I got to the end, I probably thought better of it, but forgot to delete the downstream text. I wouldn't call it incomplete, just a stopping point to see how you'd grasp the information so far.  The constructs already exist, but a good book or newsgroup would go a long way towards understanding regex technique.

Comment: I did not claim to be a regex expert, but my question was specific and it does not emanate ignorance, or merit negative marking. If the answer is indeed that there is no way to do what was asked, then I have also described that answer in the question itself. Anyway, there is no point in prolonging this discussion. Again, thanks for your time.

Comment: @PNS - Your specific question was answered with two answers here. There is no switch statement in regular expressions, nor is there a need for one.